# Why can we save images only as a square or a rectangle?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, save, image-format, shape

My question is quite simple. Why can't we save images as a circle or a triangle? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Vector images can be any shape.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11744461/2191572

Answer (score 0):

That's the convention because it's how images were made before computers were around, or even before camera's. Keeping in that standard pictures are generally the same as well.

To quote [Nielsen's Usability Heuristics](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/):

> Match between system and the real world The system should speak the
> users' language, with words, phrases and concepts familiar to the
> user, rather than system-oriented terms. Follow real-world
> conventions, making information appear in a natural and logical order.

In addition to this, PNG images can be saved as any shape you want really seeing as they support transparency.

Comment: "In addition to this, PNG images can be saved as any shape you want really seeing as they support transparency." - true, but the footprint of the image is still a rectangle.